# retrieving instance from Class object java

Tags: java, generics

I understand that the following can be done .

```
User user = new User();
user.setUsername("a");
user.setPassword("abc");

 Class c = user.getClass();
```

However I have a situation in which I have to extract the instance information from the variable "c"

Is it even possible ? . We do have a c.newInstance() method but that would create a new instance of the object User. I need to access the existing instance of the User , which was responsible for creating the "c" variable in the first place .

Thanks

-----------EDIT-----------
Looking at the comments I understood that my concept of getClass was flawed . What I want to achieve is that I need a method which would iterate over an object's getters . So what would be the signature of such ?

I was thinking on the lines of

```
public static <T> List<NameValuePair> entityConvert1(Class<T> entity)
```

however as per all the comments , I understand passing the Class wont send in any instance specific information in the method .

I need a torch here .

Comment: `c` is not linked to `user` at all, it just says what type `user` is. You'll have to revise your approach all together. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't pass the `user` variable around so the information is available directly?

Comment: If you want to extract the "guts" of `user` somehow (without there being a method on `User` to do it for you) you need to use "reflection" (or use "serialization", which internally uses reflection).

Comment: @abiessu , I need to make a generic method , hence I can't pass User directly . I need to be able to pass in any custom object , and iterate over all the getters

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib So you want to list out method names from any class?

Comment: @boxed__l not just listing out the names , I want the methods to be invoked and their values read . Is it too much to ask this

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Check my updated answer. I guess that is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

It seems like, you just want to get the getter methods from your class, and invoke it to get the value for a particular instance.

You can get all the getters using [`Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html). Write a generic method, taking 2 arguments - `Class<T>`, and `T` types:

```
public static <T> void executeGetters(Class<T> clazz, T instance) throws Exception {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);

    for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor: beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()){
        // Get Method instance used for reading this property
        Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
        // Invoke this method on 'instance'. 
        System.out.println(method.invoke(instance));
    }
}
```

Now, invoke this method as:

```
executeGetters(User.class, user);
```

This will print the value of all the properties for `user` instance. Note, if there is a getter method missing for the `User` class, this `Method` instance will be `null`, and you might get a `NPE`. You need to check for that.

Comment: my motive here is to make a method that would accept any custom object and show the value in its members . What would be the signature of such a method ? this was what I had done public static <T> List<NameValuePair> entityConvert1(Class<T> entity)

Comment: While this exactly seems to be what I want to do , I am unable to find the Introspection class here in my enviornment. I basically have to achieve this in android , and I believe android has a tuned down version of java ?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib You should have tagged the question Android too, if it is an android issue. Let me check if there is a `java.beans` package in android.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Seems like Android doesn't have `java.beans` package. You can look at this [blog post for a workaround](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-api-and-java-beans-package-2/)

Answer (score 2):

> I need to access the existing instance of the User , which was responsible for creating the "c" variable in the first place

Can't be done because there is no link between the `getClass()` method's result and `c`. The problem is that the `Class` `c` represents an instance of the type of `c` not the particular instance which is `user`. `Class` itself is a representation of the bytecode file loaded by the JVM and what it exposes so you can do reflection operations. It's not even directly analogous to the actual `User` class represented by the bytecode. It's more low level than what you're thinking.

Comment: Mike thanks for clearing this out. I am a generics noob . My motive is to make a method that would take any custom object , iterate over the getters and convert them into a namevaluepair . I am not sure what should be the signature of such a method . I was working with this public static <T> List<NameValuePair> entityConvert1(Class<T> entity) . Clearly now I beleive I can't pass in Class<T>